# Razor to talk to class function?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to add social networking buttons to my site and have build a socialNetworkingHelper class.

I would like to know what i need to do to get the view to see the helper class.

I followed the following link to get where i am now.

http://www.advancesharp.com/Blog/1033/add-facebook-twitter-and-google-plus-in-c-mvc-application

I am using MVC 4 and have placed this div in my layout page in my footer.

```
<div>
   @Html.SocialLinkButtons(Model.Title, Request.Url.ToString())
</div>
```

The SocialLinkButtons text is underlined in red with the following error message.

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for
>   'SocialLinkButtons'  and no extension method 'SocialLinkButtons'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'  could be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there somthing i must add to my view to allow the @html to call my socialLinkButtons? 
Or is there something i need to add to my class to allow this?

I have tried placing my class in the contoller folder and the models folder and just plain in the whole project. Where should this helper class be kept?

To see the class please follow the link placed above.

Edit:

---

Following the answers below the SocialLinkButtons text is no longer underlined but when i run my code i get the following error.

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named
>   'SocialLinkButtons' but appears to have an extension method by that
>   name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider
>   casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without
>   the extension method syntax.

Comment: what `namespace` did you put that code? all you need to do, and let's assumed that you add that into a `Helpers` folder is, in the first line of or View write: `@using MyNamespace.Helpers`

Comment: @balexandre here is my namespace: namespace OBASA.Controllers
{
    public static class SocialNetworkingHelper
    {

Comment: you put a helper in your Controllers namespace? That's not right! create a folder in your project and name it Helpers, then create a file called `ExtensionMethods.cs` and add that code inside, only after, add to your View, in the first line: `@using OBASA.Helpers.ExtensionMethods` - compile and run to test

Comment: You have to cast the parameters to their applicable type. It is probably Model.Title, try (string)Model.Title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shoud to put code from link in any namespace:

```
namespace Helpers {
  public static class SocialNetworkingHelper {
    ...
  }
}
```

and add using directive in your view:

```
@using Helpers
```

Comment: I renamed my name space to SoicalNetworking as it used to be OBASA.Controllers and then added the @using SocialNetworking the underlined red text is gone but i'm still left with an error please see edit.

Comment: You should to add @using in view where namespace would be used and don't forget to rebuild solution.

Comment: BTW, if you just need to add social widgets to yor pages, you can use customizable widget by `AddThis.com` or other similar service without adding any classes to project.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you extension method `SocialLinkButtons` is not visible in the view.
You should add `@using MyNamespace` directive in the view where `MyNamespace` is actual namespace of your extension method `SocialLinkButtons` or youcan achieve the same thing via `web.config` by adding this namespace to

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Collections" />
            <add namespace="MyNamespace" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: So i renamed the namespace in my calls to socialNetworking and then added the namespace like you had show but to no effect.

Comment: There is one more point that you should check.
Check that you reference right `HtmlHelper` in `public static MvcHtmlString SocialLinkButtons(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String title, String url)`. 
You should use System.Web.Mvc version not System.Web.WebPages.